# Getting net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME while calling telephone number with ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code in config.xml

```
<content src="index.html"/>
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="tel:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="true" />
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="true" />
```

This in HTML:

```
<a ng-href="tel:{{item.phone}}"><h3>Anrufen</h3></a>
```

item.phone returns 0331234567

in index.html:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<content src="index.html"/>
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="true" />
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="true" />
```

Keep these. Remove others.

These two cause *net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME* problem:

```
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
```

Comment: hi i did this and it removed the error but iphone calls doesn't work anymore.

Comment: To Shinon Chan: you need to put them inside of iOS section.
<platform name="ios">
  <allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
....